# Facing Issue with Share Extension from Sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have an iOS App which has a sqlite DB and I am trying to implement Share extension. Hence, I have this DB shared by the main App as well as the share extension.

Following is my implementation

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSString *AppGroupId = @"XXXX";
NSURL *groupContainerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:AppGroupId];
NSString *sharedDirectory = [groupContainerURL path];
sqliteDb = [sharedDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYDB.sqlite"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sqliteDb];
NSLog(@"path : %@", sqliteDb);
```

If I put my DB in NSDocument directory (without implementing share extension), everything works fine .

However, if I move it to shared directory and implement sharing extension, the app starts to crash *when it goes in background*.

Following are the logs and unfortunately I have not been able to debug why this is happening. Any help would be truly appreciated

The Crash log differ very time
 like following

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
>       0x31ae8504 <+0>:  mov    r12, sp
>       0x31ae8508 <+4>:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r8}
>       0x31ae850c <+8>:  ldm    r12, {r4, r5, r6}
>       0x31ae8510 <+12>: mvn    r12, #30
>       0x31ae8514 <+16>: svc    #0x80
>   ->  0x31ae8518 <+20>: pop    {r4, r5, r6, r8}
>       0x31ae851c <+24>: bx     lr
>
> Foundation`-[NSConcreteMapTable dealloc]:
>       0x245b6f68 <+0>:   push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
>       0x245b6f6a <+2>:   add    r7, sp, #0xc
>       0x245b6f6c <+4>:   push.w {r8, r10}
>       0x245b6f70 <+8>:   sub    sp, #0x8
>       0x245b6f72 <+10>:  mov    r4, r0
>       0x245b6f74 <+12>:  movw   r0, #0xa10
>       0x245b6f78 <+16>:  movt   r0, #0xd9f
>       0x245b6f7c <+20>:  movw   r1, #0xa0e
>       0x245b6f80 <+24>:  add    r0, pc
>       0x245b6f82 <+26>:  movt   r1, #0xd9f
>       0x245b6f86 <+30>:  add    r1, pc
>       0x245b6f88 <+32>:  ldr.w  r8, [r0]
>       0x245b6f8c <+36>:  ldr    r5, [r1]
>       0x245b6f8e <+38>:  ldr.w  r10, [r4, r8]
>       0x245b6f92 <+42>:  adds   r6, r4, r5
>       0x245b6f94 <+44>:  mov    r0, r6
>       0x245b6f96 <+46>:  mov    r1, r10
>       0x245b6f98 <+48>:  bl     0x24644e10                ; empty
>       0x245b6f9c <+52>:  ldr    r0, [r4, r5]
>       0x245b6f9e <+54>:  mov    r1, r10
>       0x245b6fa0 <+56>:  ldr    r2, [r6, #0x30]
>       0x245b6fa2 <+58>:  blx    r2
>       0x245b6fa4 <+60>:  movw   r0, #0x9e4
>       0x245b6fa8 <+64>:  mov.w  r10, #0x0
>       0x245b6fac <+68>:  movt   r0, #0xd9f
>       0x245b6fb0 <+72>:  str.w  r10, [r4, r5]
>       0x245b6fb4 <+76>:  add    r0, pc
>       0x245b6fb6 <+78>:  ldr.w  r8, [r4, r8]
>       0x245b6fba <+82>:  ldr    r5, [r0]
>       0x245b6fbc <+84>:  adds   r6, r4, r5
>       0x245b6fbe <+86>:  mov    r1, r8
>       0x245b6fc0 <+88>:  mov    r0, r6
>       0x245b6fc2 <+90>:  bl     0x24644e10                ; empty
>   ->  0x245b6fc6 <+94>:  ldr    r0, [r4, r5]
>
> etc

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * const DataBaseName  = @"MYDB.sqlite";



-(BOOL) createDataBase
{

BOOL success;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success) return success;
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

if (!success) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!!!" message:@"Failed to create writable database..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
return success;

}
```

Comment: Hi  Pradip thnx for reply! But i want to tell you pradip,the issue i am facing is that ,when i try to store sqlite database within share directory by using APP Group for sharing it with Share Extension.